# Navbar responsiveness not working bootstrap v2.2

Tags: html, responsive

I am working with **bootstrap version 2.2** that is not responsive for navbar please help me what should I do with mobile view here is my html

```
<nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner is-sticky">
            <div class="main-nav">
                <!-- Nav Menu -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li><a href="Index.aspx" type="text/html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown"
                            href="#">Our Products
                           <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                         <%
                            string tagc = "";
                            using (MarhabaWebApplication.model.marhaba_web_dbEntities db = new MarhabaWebApplication.model.marhaba_web_dbEntities())
                            {
                                tagc += "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">";
                                var cat = (from pc in db.tbl_product_category select pc).ToList();
                                for (int i = 0; i < cat.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    tagc += "<li onclick=navigatetocatpage(" + cat[i].p_c_id + ")>"+cat[i].p_c_name+"</li>";
                                }
                                tagc += "</ul>";
                            }
                            Response.Write(tagc);
                         %>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#about">about us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#contact">contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog/index.html">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Nav Menu end-->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Our Product tab is creating dynamically ignore that code that is working fine just tell me what should i do for the responsiveness thank you!
[bootstrap also telling something about navbar responsiveness](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.2.2/docs/components.html#navbar)

Comment: have you checked the stylesheet for the mobile view.?? check in your web directory there must be mobile view style sheet in that directory. try to find similar tag styles in that file.

Comment: yeah i have bootstrap-responsive.css in my directory have also included that but still its not working for me i have edit my question a link added

Comment: The menu you implemented seems belong to some template.. Check that template css and compare it with your custom css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner is-sticky">
            <div class="main-nav">
                <!-- Nav Menu -->
               <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </a>
              <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="Index.aspx" type="text/html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown"
                            href="#">Our Products
                           <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                       
                         <%
                            string tagc = "";
                            using (MarhabaWebApplication.model.marhaba_web_dbEntities db = new MarhabaWebApplication.model.marhaba_web_dbEntities())
                            {
                                tagc += "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">";
                                var cat = (from pc in db.tbl_product_category select pc).ToList();
                                for (int i = 0; i < cat.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    tagc += "<li onclick=navigatetocatpage(" + cat[i].p_c_id + ")>"+cat[i].p_c_name+"</li>";
                                }
                                tagc += "</ul>";
                            }
                            Response.Write(tagc);
                         %>
                      
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#about">about us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#contact">contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog/index.html">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
          </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Nav Menu end-->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thanx umer it is going responsive but i am unable to expand menu i am clicking on menu icon but nothing is happening

Comment: are you add bootstrap.js in your file?

Comment: add jquery.js & bootstrap.js file in your file

Comment: yeah its there brother leave it now i have an alternative solution thanks :)